# Generate results like '2015-16 season' for values like '1516REG' for this value and other years in the future

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As of now I'm handling the situation as shown below. But it is going to be a problem going forward in the future. Do I need to come up with a new table and do a join or is there any regex or substring I can use in the select statement?

[image]

I'm having a table with some values like this. So when a new value like 2223REG comes up I need to return 2022-23 Season.

```
season
-------
2021REG \n
2122REG \n
1516REG \n
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remove that case expression. It is cumbersome and not at all dynamic. You could use STUFF for this. Might a need a little tweaking if you plan on running this code in 80 years. But it will work fine until the year 2100.

```
declare @Something table(SomeVal varchar(20))

insert @Something
select '2021REG \n' union all
select '2324REG \n'

select '20' + stuff(left(s.SomeVal, 4), 3, 0, '-') + ' Season'
from @Something s
```